# How to use huggingface T5 model to test translation task?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I see there exits two configs of the T5model - **T5Model** and **TFT5WithLMHeadModel**. I want to test this for translation tasks (eg. en-de) as they have shown in the google's original repo. Is there a way I can use this model from hugging face to test out translation tasks. I did not see any examples related to this on the documentation side and was wondering how to provide the input and get the results.

Any help appreciated

Comment: My naive method was to do the following and see if it works  - 
`from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5WithLMHeadModel`

`tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-small')`

`model = T5WithLMHeadModel.from_pretrained('t5-small')`

#As suggested in their original paper
`input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("translate English to German: That is good. target:")).unsqueeze(0)`

`outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids)`

`scores, attn = outputs[:2]`
`indexes = torch.argmax(scores,dim=2)`
`predicted_token = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(indexes[0])`

Comment: this gave me the following results :

['.', '.', '▁German', '.', '▁German', '▁is', ',', '.', '</s>', ':', '</s>']

Comment: Please include your "naive approach" in the question, not the comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use *T5ForConditionalGeneration* to translate your text...

```
!pip install transformers

from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-small')

model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-small', return_dict=True)

input = "My name is Azeem and I live in India"

# You can also use "translate English to French" and "translate English to Romanian"
input_ids = tokenizer("translate English to German: "+input, return_tensors="pt").input_ids  # Batch size 1

outputs = model.generate(input_ids)

decoded = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

print(decoded)
```

As of today, *T5WithLMHeadModel* is not supported by Transformers.

Comment: Thanks!! T5Tokenizer is not working. It returns None. But T5TokenizerFast is working fine!

Comment: But to use T5 to translate anew language?

Answer (score 0):

T5 is a pre-trained model, which can be fine-tuned on downstream tasks such as Machine Translation. So it is expected that we get gibberish when asking it to translate -- it hasn't learned how to do that yet.

Comment: This is not true. HuggingeFace T5 is already pre-trained for translation